# android pre honeycomb animation of layout

Tags: android, animation, layout, margin, padding

I am trying to animate a layout to hide itself (to later animate other layout to take its place also by animation). Must be SDK 8 (android 2.2) compatible.

What I have works great IF the movingLayout's parent (parent_of_moving_layout in my xml) is twice the movingLayout's height, but I want the parent to be the same height so the movingLayout hides itself below so that I can animate another movingLayout2 later to take its place.

I have been working on it for some long hours and I can't find a solution, hoping someone has an idea (tried setFillAfter and setFillEnabled).

Here is my code and xml to reproduce the result:

activity_my.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MOVE IT"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/parent_of_moving_layout">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#ff93c049"
            android:id="@+id/movinglayout"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Test Button"
                android:id="@+id/testbutton"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="83dp"></FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MyActivity.java

```
package coersum.com.testanimation;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;


public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    //Button clicked to make movingLayout move (mButton) and button to make sure the objects moved and not only their displays (testButton)
    Button mButton, testButton;
    //layout to move and its LayoutParams (relative seems to be the only one that worked on my tests)
    RelativeLayout movingLayout;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;
    //used to direction of movement for testing
    String direction = "down";
    //just a counter to see the Log.d changes more clearly
    int count = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(mButtonClickListener);

        testButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.testbutton);
        testButton.setOnClickListener(testButtonClickListener);

        movingLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.movinglayout);
        params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) movingLayout.getLayoutParams();

    }

    private View.OnClickListener mButtonClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            TranslateAnimation animation;

            if (direction.equals("down")) {

                animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, 50);

            } else {

                animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, -50);
            }
            animation.setFillAfter(true);
            animation.setFillEnabled(true);
            animation.setDuration(500);
            animation.setAnimationListener(mAnimationListener);
            movingLayout.startAnimation(animation);
        }
    };

    private View.OnClickListener testButtonClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            count++;
            Log.d("Status", "Clicked on Test Button "+count+"  "+direction);
        }
    };

    private Animation.AnimationListener mAnimationListener = new Animation.AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            movingLayout.clearAnimation();

            if (direction.equals("down")) {

                direction = "up";
                params.topMargin = params.topMargin + 50;

            } else {

                direction = "down";
                params.topMargin = params.topMargin - 50;

            }

            movingLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
    };


}
```

Answer (score 0):

After a few more hours of trials, I found an easy and clean solution (it was really just sooo simple, animate down then set View.GONE and to bring it back, set View.VISIBLE before animating up)! Added a scale for DP and finally made the difference between margin and translation.

Here is an updated java file:

```
package coersum.com.testanimation;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;


public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    //Button clicked to make movingLayout move (mButton) and button to make sure the objects moved and not only their displays (testButton)
    Button mButton, testButton;
    //layout to move and its LayoutParams (relative seems to be the only one that worked on my tests)
    RelativeLayout movingLayout;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;
    //used to direction of movement for testing
    String direction = "down";
    //just a counter to see the Log.d changes more clearly
    int count = 0;

    int convertedSize;

    float scale;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        convertedSize = (int) (50 * scale + 0.5f); // my layout is 50dp in height set it to (minus)-your_size to go up instead of down


        mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(mButtonClickListener);

        testButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.testbutton);
        testButton.setOnClickListener(testButtonClickListener);

        movingLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.movinglayout);
        params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) movingLayout.getLayoutParams();


    }

    private View.OnClickListener mButtonClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            TranslateAnimation animation;

            if (direction.equals("down")) {
                animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, convertedSize);

            } else {
                movingLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // show the layout before to animate it
                animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, convertedSize, 0);
            }

            animation.setDuration(500);
            animation.setAnimationListener(mAnimationListener);
            movingLayout.startAnimation(animation);
        }
    };

    private View.OnClickListener testButtonClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            count++; // just for debugging (to make sure the button was gone and not just its display)
            Log.d("Status", "Clicked on Test Button " + count + "  Dir: " + direction + " Size: " + convertedSize);
        }
    };

    private Animation.AnimationListener mAnimationListener = new Animation.AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            if (direction.equals("down")) {
                movingLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE); // once it translated down, remove it so I'll be free to set other layout to visible to use etc
                direction = "up";
            } else {
                direction = "down";
            }

            movingLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
            movingLayout.clearAnimation();
        }
    };

    public void testClick(View view) {


    }


}
```

The setting of margin is good if you want to just move the layout inside the screen (and actually move the objects and not just their "display" which is what animations do below Honeycomb sdk, but that wasn't my case so this, so far seems to work perfectly.